# Cross-platform DirectShow alternatives for real life graph

Tags: cross-platform, filter, graph, directshow

Today I have such graph. I run it on windows [image]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/CO/MkvAndSampleGrabber.jpg))</sub>

I need some easy crossplatform DirectShow like alternative where to reconstruct such graph will not be a hard task.

Where can I get such alternative? *(and If you can presenta way to reconstruct such graph in It It would be grate!)

BTW: By crossplatform I mean Linux Mac and Windows compatible, By using SampleGrabber I ment I need to be able to get data from that step of graph from my programm and I use VirtualCamera from here soundmorning.com/download.php

Comment: Is directsow Microsoft's upcoming pig-simulation library? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility is [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), the concept is similar to DirectShow. Probably every Linux distribution does contain it. Windows binaries can be found [here](http://www.gstreamer-winbuild.ylatuya.es/), Mac OS X [here](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Windows binaries: Error 509: Bandwidth Limit Exceeded

Answer (score 1):

The [Phonon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/phonon-overview.html) library, which is part of [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), may be worth a look. It's a wrapper around DirectShow on Windows, Quicktime on Mac and GStreamer on Linux and has an architecture that's fairly similar to the filtergraphs of DirectShow.